# Markov chain and language/ information theory

Tags: book-recommendation

Do you have books you can recommend that deal with Markov chains and language/ information theory?

As far as I know this was one of the starting points of the theory of Markov chains.

The books should not be too complicated and detailed, firstly because I am not good in this and secondly, because I mainly have to give a short (rather introducing) presentation about this aspect of Markov chain theory. On the other hand the books should not be too non-mathematical.

Maybe you know one or two good books that deal with this or maybe books that treat this in a chapter.

Thank you for your tips!